# Is there a way to make it so when i let go of left click the red rectangle stays at the top of the box? i have tried many things but nothing works

Tags: html, css

Is there any way that I can make it so when I press the red box it stays at the top of the other box even after i have lifted my finger off left click. Do I need to use Javascript to include this function? Im fairly new to CSS and HTML so code might be sloppy or not well written but any comments are welcome and if you might have a solution it would be greatly appreciated for letting me know. I have tried using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` but it still resets the position of the red box once i let go of left click. Underneath is the HTML and CSS

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: rgb(21,21,21);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container{
  height: 425px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}

.textbox{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}


@keyframes texboxMove{
  from {border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;}
  to {border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;}
  from {border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;}
  to {border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;}
  from {margin-bottom: 0%;}
  to {margin-bottom: 91%;}
  from {border-top-left-radius: 0px;}
  to {border-top-left-radius: 22px;}
  from {border-top-right-radius: 0px;}
  to {border-top-right-radius: 22px;}
}

.textbox:active{
  animation-name: texboxMove;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="textbox"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use Javascript to add an eventlistener to sense the click and add a class to the textbox which sets the animation rather than on :active. If you don't want to use JS look into having and input of type checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class `.active` to the `textBox` when clicked. The `.active` class has the animation, set the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` on this class.

```js
function moveIt(){
document.querySelector('.textbox').classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  height: 425px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}

.textbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes texboxMove {
  from {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  }
  to {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  }
  from {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
  }
  to {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  from {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 91%;
  }
  from {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  }
  to {
    border-top-left-radius: 22px;
  }
  from {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  to {
    border-top-right-radius: 22px;
  }
}

.textbox.active {
  animation-name: texboxMove;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="textbox" onclick="moveIt()"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```